# Error deploying Python package to AWS lambda using Serverless framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I've followed [this](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging) tutorial from the serverless website to try deploy my first AWS lambda function with a package dependency.

The error I get is `STDERR: ERROR: Invalid requirement: '��' (from line 1 of /var/task/requirements.txt)` I haven't been able to find a solution on using google. Having tried to go through the tutorial various times the same error keeps reoccurring, sometimes as `ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\x00'` or `ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\x00\x01'` or something similar. It seems to me that the serverless-python-requirements plugin is formatting it's own requirement file incorrectly, but I just don't know.

My requirements.txtwhen I have no dependencies is empty, which then translates to a serverless generated .serverless\requirements.txt:

> ��

When my requirements.txt is

> numpy==1.19.2

this translates to a .serverless/requirements.txt as follows:

> ��n u m p y = = 1 . 1 9 . 2

I have gone through each step of the tutorial, and have not run into any problems until I run `serverless deploy`. This is the stack trace I get:

```
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Generated requirements from C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\requirements.txt in C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\943a69dded6372ca37aaaacaf21570a18766193003231d5130a067451373395d_slspyc\requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
Serverless: Trying bindPath C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/943a69dded6372ca37aaaacaf21570a18766193003231d5130a067451373395d_slspyc (run,--rm,-v,C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/943a69dded6372ca37aaaacaf21570a18766193003231d5130a067451373395d_slspyc:/test,alpine,ls,/test/requirements.txt)
Serverless: /test/requirements.txt
Serverless: Using download cache directory C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\downloadCacheslspyc
Serverless: Trying bindPath C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/downloadCacheslspyc (run,--rm,-v,C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/downloadCacheslspyc:/test,alpine,ls,/test/requirements.txt)
Serverless: /test/requirements.txt
Serverless: Running docker run --rm -v C\:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/4870b1f009d955f0e7d5138512661e3ec4364d6a9c1e3c6cadc9d51a7e3b8dd2_slspyc\:/var/task\:z -v C\:/Users/.../AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/downloadCacheslspyc\:/var/useDownloadCache\:z -u 0 lambci/lambda\:build-python3.8 python -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownloadCache...

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: STDOUT:

  STDERR: ERROR: Invalid requirement: '��' (from line 1 of /var/task/requirements.txt)

      at C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:325:13
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at installRequirements (C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:312:28)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:556:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (C:\Users\...\Documents\Serverless\my\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:635:29)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:498:22)
      at PluginManager.spawn (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:518:17)
      at C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy\deploy.js:122:50
  From previous event:
      at Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy\deploy.js:102:22)
      at C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:498:55
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:498:22)
      at C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:533:24
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.run (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:533:8)
      at C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:168:33
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.run (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:155:74)
      at C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:50:26
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:50:4)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:47:1)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.18.4
     Framework Version:         2.1.1
     Plugin Version:            4.0.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        3.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

- Converting the `requirements.txt` to UTF8 will fix this issue. (tested on linux)
- Try converting `requirements.txt` to ASCII.

This is the problem with requirements.txt file encoding.

## Detailed explanation

This is an open issue as on date *10th March 2022*

The serverless plugin rewrites the file into `.serverless` directory & it assumes UTF8 encoding when it reads the file.

The problem occurs as serverless attempts to read a file with another encoding & then dump it into `.serverless` folder.

[Serverless-python-requirements issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements/issues/442)

Answer (score 0):

Add dockerizePip command at the end then it will not show this error

```
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: handler.app
    pythonBin: python # Some systems with Python3 may require this
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

or delete the requirements.txt then enter serverless deploy and then paste requirements.txt and run again serverless deploy

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while deploying a Serverless application on Windows, and I was able to **resolve it by **changing the encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI****

Here are the following these steps:

- Open the requirements.txt file in Notepad.
- Click on "File" in the top-left corner of Notepad.
- Click on "Save As" in the dropdown menu that appears.
- In the "Save As" dialog box, click on the "Encoding" dropdown menu.
- Choose "ANSI" from the list of available encoding formats.
- Click on the "Save" button to save the file in the ANSI format.

After saving the file in the ANSI format, I was able to deploy the application successfully.

I hope this solution helps anyone who might be facing a similar issue on Windows. I wanted to include these steps for those who might find them helpful.